# Scripting to silently convert InDesign CS6 to CC, Save Dialog box issue

Tags: adobe-indesign, extendscript

So I'm opening a bunch of CS6 files. When I am done fixing links and other issues I'd like to just hit the keyboard shortcut to save, but no dice. It brings up the Save As dialog box and on the Mac I have to navigate around to the original file location, select the original file, and then confirm that I want to overwrite the file. I'd like to make it a silent process with a script.

Now, I understand why this is happening... The name at the top of the document ends with "[converted]" and in ExtendScript ToolKit when I try to get the CS6 documents properties to use as arguments for the save function:

```
var myDocument = app.activeDocument;
var myFileName = myDocument.fullName;

myDocument.save(File(myFileName), true);
```

I will get the following feedback:

```
Unsaved documents have no full name
```

But I'm unsure of where to go from here as I do not know how to get the filename and path from the opened (and converted/unsaved) CS6 document.

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out!
While I cannot use the fullName property I can use the filePath and name properties in conjuction with a slash.

```
var myDocument = app.activeDocument;
var myFileName = myDocument.filePath + "/" + myDocument.name

myDocument.save(File(myFileName), true);
```

Only problem would be needing to change this to a backslash for Windows I suppose. So very close to be cross platform. Feedback appreciated.

Comment: Actually Extendscript handles slash translation for you. You don't have to worry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Wooh! Thank you very much!
Using CC 2022, still works.
**Downside:**
Undos are discarded, i.e., it's a forced "Save As".
Sharing .jsx here (along with other InDesign scripts for file saving and exporting): http://ewk.in/inddscriptsfilesaveexp (link shortener) or https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1gl4dtQeE7qp5LbljmatmTmL1HW6fe-rK?usp=sharing -- **if dead link tell me. I can update the ewk.in link shortener reference.**

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that the history was saved along with the file (or when that may have been introduced). I haven't touched Adobe stuff in a few years, so I'm glad it worked for you!